# Delete Duplicate Data on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete, postgresql-9.3

How to delete duplicate data on a table which have kind data [like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP7Vk.png).
I want to keep it with the latest `updated_at` at each attribute `id`.

Like as follows:

```
attribute id | created at          | product_id
1            | 2020-04-28 15:31:11 | 112235
4            | 2020-04-28 15:30:25 | 112235
1            | 2020-04-29 15:30:25 | 112236
4            | 2020-04-29 15:30:25 | 112236
```

Comment: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-postgresql/

Comment: Looks a bit like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql

Comment: it's good using this link, but why if i have another product_id then it'll deleted.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an EXISTS condition.

```
delete from the_table t1
where exists (select *
              from the_table t2
              where t2.created_at > t1.created_at
                and t2.attribute_id = t1.attribute_id);
```

This will delete all rows where another row for the same attribute_id exists that has bigger created_at value (thus keeping only the row with the highest `created_at` for each `attribute_id`). Note that if two `created_at` values are identical, nothing will be deleted for that `attribute_id`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=654b00b9737402460f395c7d9f95dac6)